# UrlPathEncode do not escape spaces

Tags: c#

I have Url with space and would like to replace spaces with %20(escape them). UrlPathEncode should do that but it do not works on url below which has spaces. Can someone explain why it is not working?

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("http://a1.quickcatchlabs.com/phototemplates/football_blimp_1.html?i_url=http://lh3.ggpht.com/yf5lVBB_WNBvBHT1HoIzY1SG0-PY5zRCobP3vBacuSk9N346F7CeAIRSFOltR6ZC1-yf-MNKAcAd7bAZ_A=s612-c&i_name=Patriots  vs Redskins&i_venue_name=Gillette Stadium &i_venue_address=Foxborough , MA&d_Score_0=34&d_Score_1=27&d_Period_0=Final&p_name_0=Patriots &p_name_1=Redskins");
```

Comment: You try to encode the _path_, but the strings you want escaped are in the _query string_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the name implies, [UrlPathEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode.aspx) encodes the path. *Just* the path, *not* the query portion of the URL. If you add a space to path and run that code again, you will see that the space in the path portion is replaced by a `%20`, but the spaces in the query portion are not.

If you replace the call to `UrlPathEncode` with one to [Uri.EscapeUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx), it will correctly encode the entire URL, not just the path.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `Uri.EscapeDataString`.

Comment: That's a c#/javascript frankenlanguage, no?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, split the string for '?'(url.split('?')). It will give you the base path and query string. Then encode the base path with UrlPathEncode() and query string with UrlEncode(). Then append both. This would solve the problem.

Sample code:

```
public string EncodeURL(string url)
{
    var encodedURL = new StringBuilder();
    var urls = url.Split('?');
    encodedUrl.Append(HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(urls[0]));
    encodedUrl.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(urls[1]));

    return encodedUrl.ToString();
}
```

Comment: There is a problem when url contains (should not) more '?'.

Comment: In that case, use url.Split(Char[], count) and pass count=1. This would solve your problem.

Comment: This is not the main problem by my current understanding the UrlEncode escapes the query string as a whole and so & is not interpreted as separator when the query string is interpreted correctly on accepting page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri.EscapeDataString("this is a test")
```

gives

```
this%20is%20a%20test
```